# Is there a way to convert FAT16 to NTFS using terminal without convert.exe?

Tags: windows-7, windows, filesystems, ntfs, conversion

Do you know any other ways of converting filesystems in Windows 7 only by means of the OS itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The OS cannot do anything. That's the utilities do their part. Convert.exe is the only command line tool to convert to NTFS in windows